# Browse array row by row in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
for link in soup.find_all("td", class_="textleft",limit=30):
    a = link.find('a').attrs['href']
    print(a)
```

This returns me 30 objects:

```
/HORTICHUELAS-N-4812.html
/ISABEL-ALONSO.html
/TRANS-CEREZUELA.html
/NATURE-CHOICE.html
/AGRUPA-INVER.html
/HERBEX-IBERIA.html
/HORTOFRUTICOLA-NORIAS-ALMERIA.html
/GARCIDEN.html
/CASUR.html
/HORTOSABOR-MEDITERRANEO.html
/GRUPO-CONTROL-EMPRESA-SEGURIDAD.html
/VEGACANADA.html
/ONDUSPAN.html
/EJIDOMAR-AND.html
/ENZA-ZADEN-ESPANA.html
....
...
```

so up to 30 results as I can go putting each result in a variable, iterating with each of the results one by one for example

```
var 1 = /SOTRAFA.html
var 2 = /AGROPONIENTE.html
```

Comment: Do you want to put each result in a variable?

Comment: yes, each element in a variable

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57647878/9093112 - what do you think about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would recommend using a `list` instead of different variables.
lists are better suited for storing and iterating over a collection of values.

```py
# accumulate links
my_list = []
for link in soup.find_all("td", class_="textleft",limit=30):
    a = link.find('a').attrs['href']
    print(a)
    my_list.append(a)

# display links
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print('var', i, '=', my_list[i])
```

Comment: I reccomend using enumerate instead of range(len())

Comment: @BaileyKocin yes this would be preferable, i chose not to use it here to demonstrate how to retrieve values from a list

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: class Result: 
   ...:     pass 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [2]: var = Result()                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [3]: setattr(var, 'var1', '/SOTRAFA.html')                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [4]: setattr(var, 'var2', '/AGROPONIENTE.html')                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [5]: var.var1                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[5]: '/SOTRAFA.html'

In [6]: var.var2                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[6]: '/AGROPONIENTE.html'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr